# Error while calculating taxes: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, string, selenium

I try to calculate my taxes using python, but I get:

> ```
> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
> ```

Code:

```
price_without_taxes = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='__next']/div/main/div/div/div/p/span").text
print('LE PRIX EST DE :' + price_without_taxes)
tps = price_without_taxes * 0.05
tvq = price_without_taxes * 0.09975

price_with_taxes = float((price_without_taxes + tps + tvq))
print("Sous-Total: " + "%1.2f" % price_with_taxes + "$\n")
print("Livraison: " + str(10) + "$\n")
print("Total: " + "%1.2f" % price_with_taxes + "$\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`price_without_taxes` is a string, not a number.
In order to multiply it by `float` you have to convert it to a number.
python is "clever" enough to multiple string containing a number only by `int`, however it doesn't know how to multiply a string containing a number by `float`.
This should work better:

```py
price_without_taxes = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='__next']/div/main/div/div/div/p/span").text
print('LE PRIX EST DE :' + price_without_taxes)
#converting "price_without_taxes" from string to float object
price_without_taxes = float(price_without_taxes)
tps = price_without_taxes * 0.05
tvq = price_without_taxes * 0.09975

price_with_taxes = float((price_without_taxes + tps + tvq))
print("Sous-Total: " + "%1.2f" % price_with_taxes + "$\n")
print("Livraison: " + str(10) + "$\n")
print("Total: " + "%1.2f" % price_with_taxes + "$\n")
```

**UPD**
In case the text extracted from the web element with Selenium contains signs like `$` you can extract the number from that string with the following piece of code:

```py
import re
price_without_taxes = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", price_without_taxes)
```

So, the complete solution will be:

```py
import re
price_without_taxes = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='__next']/div/main/div/div/div/p/span").text
print('LE PRIX EST DE :' + price_without_taxes)
#converting "price_without_taxes" from string to float object
price_without_taxes = re.sub('[^0-9,]','', price_without_taxes)
price_without_taxes = price_without_taxes.replace(",", ".")
price_without_taxes = float(price_without_taxes)
tps = price_without_taxes * 0.05
tvq = price_without_taxes * 0.09975

price_with_taxes = float((price_without_taxes + tps + tvq))
print("Sous-Total: " + "%1.2f" % price_with_taxes + "$\n")
print("Livraison: " + str(10) + "$\n")
print("Total: " + "%1.2f" % price_with_taxes + "$\n")
```

Comment: I think the problem in my example when i get the text from the element i get 990,00 $ so it's a number + $ . so how can i get just 990,00?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Please let me know if now it works correct

Comment: I try your code and i have this result when i print : ['360,00'] but i need this 360,00 without ['']. and replacing , by . 
and after i use 360.00* 0.5 and 360.00*0.09975. so how to get this please?

Comment: Do you mean even after applying `re.findall("\d+\.\d+", price_without_taxes)` the `[]` still not removed?

Comment: yes always have []

Comment: Instead of `re.findall("\d+\.\d+", price_without_taxes)` please try `re.findall("[0-9]*\,?[0-9]*", price_without_taxes)` Please let me know it this removes all you need to remove. To replace `.` with `,` after that use this: `price_without_taxes = price_without_taxes..replace(".", ",")`

Comment: Please let me know if that worked

Comment: For the price i get ['765,00', '', '', '', '']
For replace i get : Unresolved attribute reference 'replace' for class 'list'

Comment: OK, what is the original value of `price_without_taxes` before applying the `re.findall` ?

Comment: its a text 45,00 $

Comment: I see.. Please try this: `price_without_taxes = re.sub('[^0-9,]','', price_without_taxes)` . let me know if now it works. I don't really know python, coding Java :)

Comment: Thanks a lot this is the code and its work for me :
price_without_taxes = re.sub('[^0-9,]', '', price_without_taxes)
        # price_without_taxes = re.findall(r'(?:\d+\.)?\d+,\d+', price_without_taxes)
        print(price_without_taxes)
        price_without_taxes = price_without_taxes.replace(",", ".")
        print(price_without_taxes)
        price_without_taxes = float(price_without_taxes)

Comment: You do not need to use `price_without_taxes = re.findall(r'(?:\d+\.)?\d+,\d+', price_without_taxes)` anymore. This line `price_without_taxes = re.sub('[^0-9,]', '', price_without_taxes)` removes all signs that are not digits or `,`. Then you need to replace `,` with `.` - it is done by ` price_without_taxes = price_without_taxes.replace(",", ".")` finally you are converting a string to float with `price_without_taxes = float(price_without_taxes)`

Comment: price_without_taxes = re.sub('[^0-9,]', '', price_without_taxes) give me 100,00 so i need tp replace , by .

Comment: It is done by `price_without_taxes = price_without_taxes.replace(",", ".")`

Comment: the `replace` method takes 2 parameters: what to replace and with what to replace

Comment: yes i do it and works fine

Answer (score 2):

Your variable, `prices_without_taxes` is a string rather than an `int`/`float`. You can not multiply text by `float`s. You would have to convert your string to an `int`/`float` first: `float(prices_without_taxes) * (multiple)`

Comment: @Prophet and then folks on SO are confused as to why this site is seen as hostile to newcomers. why did you write this comment? just to make them feel miserable about not being as good at coding as you are? why not take the time and point out the problem in a constructive and friendly way?

Comment: @Neuron he could read my answer here as well as several others dealing with the error mentioned in the question title. BTW your "edit" totally changed his initial answer, you know...

Comment: They asked a question, I gave an answer.

Comment: I think the problem in my example when i get the text from the element i get 990,00 $ so it's a number + $ . so how can i get just 990,00?

Comment: @Prophet yes, I fixed some small mistakes. certainly a better way of showing them what was wrong with their post.

Comment: @FlutterLover take a look at the "replace" method which you can call on any string. you can use it to discard characters of the string you are not interested it. but its a problem you can easily find a solution for by googling it :)